# How to texture map a JPG image referenced in an MTL file of an object using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

How do I do that? I'm currently using Nate Robin's GLM but I don't think it supports this kind fo texturing?

Comment: Do you have any experience with an image library?

Comment: No, not at all. GLM does not support texture maps that are images like JPGs, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL - How to use an mtl file to map textures to an obj using GLM or any other loader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634084/opengl-how-to-use-an-mtl-file-to-map-textures-to-an-obj-using-glm-or-any-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at GLM's source. It seems there is no direct support of texture loading (even texture binding). But, texture coordinates are usable. So, you have to manually handle texture loading and binding. As a beginning, I recommend to use some raw images (you can directly load into a array). Later you can pick up a proper library. If size matters, [NanoJPEG](http://keyj.emphy.de/nanojpeg/) can be a wise choice.

For learning how to apply textures, [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/) is a tutorial from defacto OpenGL tutorial series.

Comment: What about this? http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/ 
Ever used it/heard about it? Does it do what I want? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thing is, I know how to map textures to something as simple as a cube, but that if I have something huge and complicated? How do I do that? That's why I need something to do it for me. What do the 'vt's in the obj file represent exactly? I know they're texture coordinates but that's it. And how are they linked to the mtl file or the images referenced in my mtl file.

Comment: I've looked the link which you've posted. It seems a bit bloated. It supports DevIL, SDL, jpeglib, pnglib with external libraries. Also, supports PPM natively as original GLM. As to your 2nd question, seems you lack of some basics. MTL file only consists several parameters and material name. Texture coordinates are loaded from OBJ file. You have to worry only texture loading and binding (use material name). You can call glmDraw() after binding. BTW, 'vt's are texture coordinates.

Comment: I just used that enhanced GLM but it won't load the texture correctly. It ignores my refraction indices which are my 'Ni's in my mtl file and warns me about that. It also warns me about how it ignores my 'Ke' commands and my 'map_Ka' commands which also exist in my mtl file.

This is how part of my mtl file looks like, the Xs represent numbers:
newmtl mymtl1
 Ns X
 Ni X
 d X
 Tr X
 Tf X 
 illum X
 Ka X
 Kd X
 Ks X
 Ke X
 map_Ka image.jpg
 map_Kd image.jpg

Comment: I never used GLM. So, it's not possible to know every parts. If I were you, as a first attempt, I would write a very simple texture loading and binding for all models which you want to draw.

Comment: I'm still having problems understanding texture binding.. I need a really good and easy tutorial to help me with textures as a whole. Texturing an image to a quad is easy, but what I don't understand is how to texture an image through the mtl file, I mean how do you map that to a certain vertex? Thanks for everything so far, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: You don't need to map anything. Texture coordinates are already in OBJ file.

Comment: OK. Here is very short code what I mean: http://pastebin.com/qJXsk6Pc I highly advice you to have look a tutorial to understand how texturing works before fighting with a 3rd library.